# Why is the infowindow not above the marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use different images as marker icons. For a small unscaled icon like

```
smallIcon = {
        url: 'img/small_icon.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(15, 15),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8)
    };
```

everything works fine. But for a larger scaled image like

```
largeIcon = {
      url: 'img/gruen_aus_rechts.png',
      size: new google.maps.Size(582, 658),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(15, 16.96)
    };
```

when I open an infoWindow it is not placed above the marker, but somewhere to the very far right on the map. Why is this happening?

PS: the large image that is used is : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I1fE.png

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post the gruen_aus_rechts.png

Comment: Just added the gruen_aus_rechts.png.